# Android adb devices cannot find any devices

Tags: android, adb, device

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and I used Android-studio before. I do remember that I could use a real device to run the app.

Today I cannot find any devices.

I tried:
cat 51-android.rules   (readable and lists a lots of devices)
adb devices   (even with sudo) does not list any device
adb kill-server
adb start-server 
sudo service udev restart
lsusb  also does not find any more device

I run out of ideas what I still could check. I changed even the usb cable.

Comment: what is your device ?

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but have you enabled USB debugging on your device?

Comment: Try to update the driver of the device find in control panel so it automatically find in studio when you connected the device.

Comment: Have you installed phone specific drivers in your machine? Also, the phone should be unlocked and USB debugging should be enabled in the system!

Comment: device is a MTK tablet. I use the https://github.com/snowdream/51-android/blob/master/51-android.rules - which should include this tablet. I have send a message to the factory again to verify, that it is include. USB debugging is enabled. What kind of phone specific drivers for Linux ??? Unlocking is not necessary, actually from there we start, since I need read/write access to the serial port.

Comment: I am getting more and more confused!!! I have an EeePC and I plugged in the tablet and it is immediately recognized, without any settings. On my desktop it is not recognized, although I have put into the 51-android.rules the line:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0c03",MODE="0666"

What could be the reason? How to fix that?

Comment: I changed the cable again, ... and after a couple times of plugin/out it works

Answer (score -1):

1. You would have to install the phone specific driver software (Example Samsung Kies for Samsung phones). Without the particular driver installed, the mobile device would not be recognized by Android's Run Application.
2. Your mobile phone should be unlocked
3. USB debugging should be enabled.
4. USB rights should be provided for the system.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try to "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" in Developers options on your device. Sometimes it really helps! Especially if everything worked fine before.